# recognizing both space delimiter and newline character in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, input, newline, delimiter

In programming competitions, often the input given is of the form:

```
1 3 5 544
4 
2 3 22
2423 
2
```

where there are multiple lines of integers delimited by a space. I've been trying to figure out how to read these input in C or C++ but could never really get it to work. Solutions that I've found on the web either use scanf or getline (or fget) but whenever I tried, they either failed to recognize the newline character or, when I tried to use them in conjunction with a for loop, the first iteration wasn't executed.

How do the competitive programmers read this type of input?

Comment: Hi. Please show us the code which failed.

Comment: We use `std::ifstream::operator>>`. You can treat newlines as space.

Comment: `std::getline` consumes the newline but doesn't append it to the string. Why do you care about the newline anyway? Presumably these challenges have static input, and you don't need to worry about doing things dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

Read the stream line-by-line using `getline()` (suggested the "getline function", which works with `std::string`, not the "getline method of istream").

Then to extract the numbers use `std::istringstream` initialized with a string read by `getline()` call.

Comment: This is not good solution for competentive programming - too much overhead.

Answer (score -1):

In competentive programming - don't use C++ input at all - it's too slow and it will reflect on your times badly (especially if expected solution is in O(n) or faster). Program specifications are usually created in such a way, that trivial scanf will do the job (intentionally, so you can focus on algorithm instead of reading input). Your problem is that probably you want to parse whitespace and don't know how to do this (with scanf - you don't need to). For example, let's parse multiple lines containing two integers separated by space:

```
int x, y;
while (foo) {
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
}
```

This will work just fine, you don't need to worry about newlines at all.
If you will get into situation, that scanf is too slow (it might be in competitions) - you will probably need to create your own dedicated parsing function by calling getchar and processing input byte by byte.

Comment: If time matters for you, and C++ is too slow - C is even slower, especially if you use parsing and interpreting, as functions like `printf` or `scanf` do (C++ iostreams don't do any such things and that's why they are faster). If you really want to have a **completely no overhead** solution, use direct reading by system functions, such as `read()`, in this case from the channel with descriptor `0`. Also, use only static arrays with fixed size, read the stream partially, and read characters one by one - this way you can see if it's space, number or EOL (scanf also uses tmp dynamic buf).

Comment: @Ethouris you're wrong. Just to make sure, I did test to read 10^6 lines of two integers - `scanf` was on average 3 times faster than `std::cin` and 6 times faster than `std::getline` + `std::istringstream`, thus `scanf` is good solution for input for competentive programming. Using `read` is a bit pointless - your timing will be similar to using `getchar`, but parsing input will be much harder - your implementation time would be better spent on algorithm instead of minor io optimizations at this point.

Comment: Mhm. Didn't you forget to turn off sync_with_stdio() in iostreams before doing the test? How many data did you use and did you check how big percentage of time has been spent with initialization and with the real operation?

Comment: Possibly the algorithmic optimization might be a good solution - except that you haven't proposed any.